# Early Childhood Caries treatment

Tags: dentistry, tooth-extraction

My 3 yo has Early Childhood Caries since he was around 1yo, 3 of his 4 upper teeth are rotten.

I've asked around and the best solution from Dentists has been the recommendation of extraction of the 3 pieces. He has already received treatment of a layer of resin on all his teeth, and we are waiting for him to develop all his molars so there is some place to put the crown on, proceed with the extraction and put on some replacement until he develops his permanent teeth.

My question is: Is the extraction the only option? Is there some risk associated with letting his rotten teeth in place and wait for his permanent ones to come out?

Comment: It's rather painful to leave rotten ones in place. Also portions of them could break off and could become a choking hazard or cause cuts/scratches if swallowed.